# How to protect user permissions?

Tags: java, authentication, authorization, shiro

I am quite new to user authentication.

I want to implement a user authentication and authorization in my Java application (no network stuff, just plain dekstop). I found Apache Shiro as a suitable library. It is probably a bit too big for my needs, but why to invent the wheel twice.
The users can authenticate with username and password. The password is salted and hashed and stored somewhere (in my case in a file). The user permissions are stored in the same file. The permissions are  not protected (except the file is a binary created with Java serialization). I created my own Realm. Works fine.

So everybody who has access to the file can edit the file and give all desired permissions to a certain user.

I know Shiro is more designed for storing accounts in a database. So is Shiro not suitable for user authentication stored in a file?

I thought I could hash the permissions and validate the hash. But why do I need Shiro then? I would expect Shiro to do this as an library for authentication and authorization.

Did I understand something totally wrong or did I miss some functionality in the Shiro library.

How is user authorization done correctly when storing data in a file?

Comment: (1). encrypt the file with a propietary certificate so noone can change it.

Comment: Anything your application can do, the user can also do.  Unless you have an external resource, this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @RomaonBoza When you post your comment as an answer I would accept it.